# linq group by and order by on some list?

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a list(avgEnergyObj) like

```
Timestamp | MeterID | Energy
----------------------------
190990001 |    1    | 98090.0
190990003 |    2    | 98909.3
190990002 |    2    | 99000.3
190990004 |    1    | 99900.9
```

i want to sort it by time stamp and group by meterID like -

```
Timestamp | MeterID | Energy
----------------------------
190990001 |    1    | 98090.0
190990003 |    2    | 99000.3
190990002 |    1    | 98909.3
190990004 |    2    | 99900.9
```

i have written something (not working) some error -

```
List<FetchingEnergy> avgEnergyObj2 =
    avgEnergyObj.GroupBy(p => p.MeterId)
                .Select(group =>
                    new {
                        meterID = group.Key,
                        FetchingEnergy = group.OrderBy(x => x.TimeStamp)
                    })
                .OrderBy(group => group.FetchingEnergy.First().TimeStamp);
```

Comment: While you formatted very nicely your tables, why don't you spend some time formatting actual code and making it compilable? (`group` is a reserved C# keyword, probably you meant `@group`)

Comment: group by is for linq, i am sure of that

Comment: I suppose there is some mistake in second table as it isn't sorted nor grouped

Comment: i want it that way grouped by meter id and time stamp sorted for each meter id

Comment: Ilya Ivanov means where you have used group as the variable (you notice it is highlighted blue) you should use either something like g or x or specify a variable name that is not reserved word in C# language. With regards to your question the tables you showed are not grouping by MeterID they are sorting on both MeterID and Energy which could be achieved by avgEnergyObj1.OrderBy(e => e.Energy).ThenBy(m => m.MeterID). Edit: Just saw Jakub's comment, he is correct about the sorting. I looked at the table and assumed you were sorting on energy.

Comment: How about something like this ?
List<FetchingEnergy> avgEnergyObj2 = avgEnergyObj.GroupBy(p => p.MeterId).Select
    (g => new { meterID = g.Key, FetchingEnergy = 
        g.OrderBy(x => x.TimeStamp) }).OrderBy
            (o => o.FetchingEnergy.First().TimeStamp).SelectMany(o => o.FetchingEnergy);

Comment: @Romain i want it in list but your sol not working. it says cannot convert IEnumerable <fetchingEnergy> to generic list <fetchingEnergy>

Comment: just add a .ToList() at the end ! ;)

Comment: or new List(...IEnumerable...) ?

Comment: Could you express the ordering rule _in words_? You don't give enough data to infer it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var sortedList = avgEnergyObj
    .OrderBy(x => x.MeterId)
    .ThenBy(x => x.TimeStamp)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Kind of the same as I put in my comment but I would say this is what was required.

Comment: Probably I just typed my answer in the same time with you

Comment: @Demarsch good one but i wanted all the attributes that were in avgEnergyObj. Can't we have list rather than var?

Comment: @DaveWilliams is there any way of having other attributes of list? and what structure var will return?

Comment: I think you need to go look up the var keyword. For now enough to say that it will return a list of whichever objects you had in the original list only in the order you wanted.

Comment: @DaveWilliams i have seen its giving sequence like all time stamps and then meter ids in order like - meter id 0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2 but i wanted 0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2 meter id sequence

Comment: @DaveWilliams meter id should be in groupings not in order

Comment: If you want to have List<> explicitly then just replace var with List<FetchingEnergy>. If you want latter meter id sequence then just repalce .OrderBy and .ThenBy arguments

Comment: I think you need to adjust your original question as it is misleading with the tables. I will post an answer.

Comment: @DaveWilliams no its in right order in table grouped by 1,2,1,2. first sorting timestamp in order then grouping meter ids in step 2 ..it doesn't matter whether timestamp goes a little out of order then

Comment: The MeterID column is NOT grouped. Grouping results in more than one collection (IGroupings). I would have thought this would be much more useful to you than the tables above but that is not the question. What your table illustrates is a sorting on Timestamp and a sub sort of MeterId.

Comment: @DaveWilliams but how to do that?

Comment: I honestly have no idea at the moment... I think that it would be very complex to achive and I can't really think of a reason why you would want to. What are you actually wanting to do with the result?